# vsftpd does not give a valid certificate using CA cert

Tags: ssl, ftp, ssl-certificate, tls, vsftpd

When setting up vsftpd we have problems with it not providing a trusted connection us a basic pem certificate container using just our private key and certificate.

We created our pem file with the following commands.

> cat somecert.com.crt >> somepem.pem
> cat somecertkey.com.key >> somepem.pem

## SSL Certificate config vsftpd.conf

> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
> ssl_enable=YES
> ssl_tlsv1=YES
> rsa_cert_file=/etc/httpd/ssl/somepem.pem

When connecting using lftp in debug mode
I saw that we giving a certificate with out enough info
to be establish the full chain of authority. To ensure
it was trusted.

> lftp -d -u user:pass myserver.com
> ....
> ERROR: Certificate verification: Not trusted
> **** Certificate verification: Not trusted
> ---- Closing control socket

Answer (score 2):

I need to get the full chain of authority and add it to the pem certificate container 
Thanks to [stackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886248/619760) there are some nice solutions to this problem.

> echo connect | openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:443 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cert.pem

From that we can now update the certificate we created to include the full chain of authority.

We need to update the [config of the vsftpd](http://tecadmin.net/install-vsftpd-with-ssl-tls-on-linux)

> vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
>   ssl_enable=YES
>   ssl_tlsv1=YES
>   rsa_private_key_file=/etc/httpd/ssl/somepem.pem
>   rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/ssl/cert.pem

Test using lftp

> lftp -d -u user:pass myserver.com
>
> Certificate: C=US,ST=Arizona,L=Scottsdale,O=Starfield Technologies\,  Inc.,OU=http://certificates.starfieldtech.com/repository,CN=Starfield Secure Certification > Authority,serialNumber=10688435
>   Issued by:        C=US,O=Starfield Technologies\, Inc.,OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
>   Checking against: C=US,O=Starfield Technologies\, Inc.,OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
>    Trusted
>   Certificate: C=US,O=Starfield Technologies\, Inc.,OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
>   Issued by: C=US,O=Starfield Technologies\, Inc.,OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
>    Trusted

It is important to pack the pem file correctly in the correct order.
[how-do-i-make-my-own-bundle-file-from-crt-files](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/643/0/how-do-i-make-my-own-bundle-file-from-crt-files)

[Creating a .pem with the Entire SSL Certificate Trust Chain](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm)

Log into your DigiCert Management Console and download your Intermediate (DigiCertCA.crt), Root (TrustedRoot.crt), and Primary Certificates (your_domain_name.crt).
Open a text editor (such as wordpad) and paste the entire body of each certificate into one text file in the following order:

1. The Primary Certificate - your_domain_name.crt
2. The Intermediate Certificate - DigiCertCA.crt
3. The Root Certificate - TrustedRoot.crt

Make sure to include the beginning and end tags on each certificate. The result should look > like this:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   (Your Primary SSL certificate: your_domain_name.crt)
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   (Your Intermediate certificate: DigiCertCA.crt)
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   (Your Root certificate: TrustedRoot.crt)
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Save the combined file as your_domain_name.pem. The .pem file is now ready to use.

Answer (score -1):

You could always configure your ftp client to ignore certificates. Which is insecure, and should be avoided. Do this at your own risk. 
http://anils-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/lftp-fatal-error-certificate.html

> lftp user@test.ftp.com:/directory
>   Password:
>   cd: Fatal error: Certificate verification: Not trusted

To disable certificate verification in lftp, completely.
`This is not a good idea if you are concerned about security`

> cat ~/.lftp/rc
>   set ssl:verify-certificate no

or
If you just want to do this for one specific host you can.

> lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no" user@test.ftp.com:/directory

Comment: Why not completely remove SSL? This is about the same security as you get with your proposal to disable certificate validation. No validation means easy man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Because some time you just want to get it done so you can leave the office. Which is why I put the correct way to do things first and then as a last attempt you can end here to just make things work.

Comment: I agree that sometimes one has to use a temporary and insecure workaround. But this should be explicitly marked as such and not as "you could always...." without pointing out that this is only a workaround and which problems it has.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you are correct. I should have take more time to explain the security implications. Thank you for your help